# application defined or object-defined error with if statement

Tags: excel, vba, object, if-statement

whenever i try to run this code i get that error on the if statement and i don't know why, please be advicsed that rcolor and info are defined and work perfectly i just chose not to put them here since they are quite long and won't affect the question in any way
and M8 is brought from a different sub

```
Sub Schedule(M8 As Variant)
If eTime = "900" Then
retry1:
    If IsEmpty(Cells(8, M8).Value) And IsEmpty(Cells(12, M8).Value) = True Then
        Sheets("Schedule").Cells(8, M8).Value = info
        Sheets("Schedule").Range(Cells(9, M8), Cells(12, M8)).Value = ","
        Sheets("Schedule").Range(Cells(8, M8), Cells(12, M8)).Interior.Color = rcolor
        Sheets("Schedule").Range(Cells(8, M8), Cells(12, M8)).BorderAround Weight:=xlMedium
        M8 = M8 + 1
    Else
        M8 = M8 + 1
        GoTo retry1
    End If
```

i've been stuck on this issue for quite a long time and would appreciate any help, thnx in advance.

Comment: `If IsEmpty(Cells(8, M8).Value` you qualified all the other `cells`, why not this one?

Comment: You seem to be missing an `End if` and a `end Sub` is it just a copy-paste error?

Comment: the end if and end sub is just a copy paste error yes i forgot to add them but what do you mean by qualifying the other cells?

Comment: When you want to compare two `.Value` then you should make sure that they are actually comparable and do not contain errors such as `#DIV/0!` (which cannot be compared). The function `IsError()` might help. Also you might want to include an "ending column" to avoid getting into an endless loop with your `GoTo`.

Comment: the funny thing is that i am not joking when i say this but it was working perfectly until i added the code for the cell borders, that's when i started getting that issue otherwise there were none

Comment: can someone plz explain what do you mean by qualifying a cell @findwindow

Comment: Did you not see @ScottHoltzman answer?  He shows you how and what is meant.

Comment: i tried to add the with Sheets... but still it didnt work

Comment: Did you put the `.` in front of the requisite `Range` and `Cells` like his example.

Answer (score 2):

As @findwindow mentioned, you need to assign parentage to all your objects (ranges) to make sure the code executes *exactly* as you wish.

You can do this neatly with a `With` block. Otherwise, if you don't assign the exact object to work with, the code will just look to the last active object, which may not be what you desire.

```
With Sheets("Schedule")

    If IsEmpty(.Cells(8, M8).Value) And IsEmpty(.Cells(12, M8).Value) Then

        .Cells(8, M8).Value = info
        .Range(.Cells(9, M8), .Cells(12, M8)).Value = ","
        .Range(.Cells(8, M8), .Cells(12, M8)).Interior.Color = rcolor
        .Range(.Cells(8, M8), .Cells(12, M8)).BorderAround Weight:=xlMedium

        M8 = M8 + 1

    Else

        M8 = M8 + 1
        GoTo retry1

    End If

End WIth
```